# Got a warning when delegating the onChange event on form element instead to each sub-element individually in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning the React and try to build a Form component to submit the data, I referred the react official doc with respect to [handling multiple inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) in form.

As you can see from the example code, it defines the `onChange={this.handleInputChange}` on each input element, I tried to hoist the `onChange` event to the `form` element itself like `<form onChange={this.handleInputChange} >` and get rid of them from each input element, then it works well based on the `change` event can be bubbled.

But I'm wondering whether this way has any side effects because I haven't seen too much code like this when searching on the Internet, and most articles regarding React form is using the same way in React's doc.

Update:
I created a MyForm component based on the examples of React site as below,
https://codepen.io/Lenient/pen/PyLwxp?editors=0010
Please note I put the `onChange` event to the form element. And you can see there are two warning messages in the console if you open the developer tool. Here is one of the messages.

> Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

I'm not very clear about it, anyone can give an example to help me understand it?

Comment: You may attach the onChange event on form without any issues as long as you have a definite way of knowing which input the change was triggered on. Most examples that you see might have multiple different types of fields which might need handling in different ways